# CSS Background Style Not Applying?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have started styling for my new websites navigation bar however my background color isn't working for it or any other Divs that I use, Div IDs are not being picked up either. My whole style seems to be messing up and this has never happened before.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="bar">
      <img src="/img/NavBar/Logo.png">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    </div>

CSS:
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background:url("/img/Global/Background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

//*NAV BAR*//
.bar {
  background-color: #0F0F0F;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.bar a {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
.bar img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

The CSS is connected because my background image is showing, however background colours are not showing. I have tried different colours to make sure that it's not just poor contrast between the background image and the colour itself as well.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong here?

Comment: I don't believe '//' is valid to start a comment in CSS. Try using /*NAV BAR*/ and remove the extra slashes on each side. It is probably was is causing the other styles to not apply.

Comment: It looks like all of `.bar`'s children are `float`ed, so it's ending up with a height of zero.

Comment: @TrentJohnson Thank you so much, I knew it would have been a stupid mistake haha! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the `//*NAV BAR*//` comment. `//` isn't valid CSS comment syntax. It makes your whole CSS file invalid. Replace it with `/*NAV BAR*/`